# Summary query returns duplicate values MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, aggregate

I have to do a report for tickets requested on my system.

The tickets are called from a workstation, and that workstation is related to many areas.

```
  SELECT
   DATE(q.created_at)   AS DATE,
   HOUR(q.created_at)   AS HOUR,
   ar.name              AS area,
   w.name               AS workstation,
   COUNT(DISTINCT q.id) AS count
  FROM qms_queue q
  JOIN qms_workstations w ON q.workstation_id = w.id
  JOIN qms_area_workstation aw ON aw.workstation_id = w.id
  JOIN qms_areas ar ON aw.area_id = ar.id
  WHERE q.created_at
      BETWEEN '2018-02-26 00:00:00'
      AND '2018-02-28 23:59:59'
      AND customer_id = 1
  GROUP BY DATE(q.created_at), w.id, HOUR(q.created_at)
  ORDER BY DATE(q.created_at), HOUR(q.created_at)
```

Doing that query, I get the total count for the tickets.

```
  SELECT
   DATE(q.created_at)   AS DATE,
   HOUR(q.created_at)   AS HOUR,
   ar.name              AS area,
   w.name               AS workstation,
   COUNT(DISTINCT q.id) AS count
  FROM qms_queue q
  JOIN qms_workstations w ON q.workstation_id = w.id
  JOIN qms_area_workstation aw ON aw.workstation_id = w.id
  JOIN qms_areas ar ON aw.area_id = ar.id
  WHERE q.created_at
      BETWEEN '2018-02-26 00:00:00'
      AND '2018-02-28 23:59:59'
      AND customer_id = 1
  GROUP BY DATE(q.created_at), w.id, HOUR(q.created_at), ar.id
  ORDER BY DATE(q.created_at), HOUR(q.created_at)
```

However, doing that query gets the absolute total count for each of the areas.

I can't figure out a way of counting the partial count for each of the areas.

Can someone give me a hand on this?

Comment: so `COUNT(DISTINCT q.id) AS count` is equal across different `ar.name`, right? it must not be so.

Comment: Exactly, that is my problem, on each ar.name the count is equal to the total

Comment: @Parfait just checked at PostgreSQL 9.4, once I group by primary key I'm free to use any other column without implicitly adding that into `group by` section. So this easing is not typical to MySQL only

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing actual data, consider simply running distinct aggregations, one at the *Area* level and one at *Workstation* level and NOT both. If needed join both as derived table subqueries by *Date* and *Hour*:

**Area level**

```
SELECT
    DATE(q.created_at)   AS `DATE`,
    HOUR(q.created_at)   AS `HOUR`,
    ar.name              AS `area`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT q.id) AS `area_count`
...
GROUP BY DATE(q.created_at), HOUR(q.created_at), ar.name
ORDER BY DATE(q.created_at), HOUR(q.created_at)
```

**Workstation level**

```
SELECT
   DATE(q.created_at)   AS `DATE`,
   HOUR(q.created_at)   AS `HOUR`,
   w.name               AS `workstation`,
   COUNT(DISTINCT q.id) AS `ws_count`
...
GROUP BY DATE(q.created_at), HOUR(q.created_at), w.name
ORDER BY DATE(q.created_at), HOUR(q.created_at)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi I don't have your data setup but try analytic function for this

```
COUNT(q.id) OVER (PARTITION BY  ar.name)
```

check this if it is working to give counts for each area.

Comment: OP said MySQL.  It doesn't have window function.  Don't post solution that don't work!!!